# How to plot 2d array in a colored 2d-colored-histogram in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, matplotlib

I have a list of shape 31x4240 which looks like

[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wyYrj.png)

Each row contains 4240 random values. My objective is to create a colored 2d-histogram, where the distribution of the 4240 random values is represented in a colored bar parallel to the y-axis, similar to this:

[2d-histogram for 2d-array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fv8rn.jpg)

I have already seen mentions of using hist2d like this:

```
x = np.random.normal(size=50000)
y = x * 3 + np.random.normal(size=50000)
plt.hist2d(x, y, bins=(50, 50), cmap=plt.cm.jet)
plt.show()
```

But i dont really see how i can use this in my scenario, since x and y are both 1D and my array is 2D

Does anyone have a clue?

Comment: Creating a histogram could be hard, as you don't seem to have histogramable data. But you could try `plt.pcolormesh(your_2d_array, cmap='turbo')` to display the data.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `imshow`:

```py
im = plt.imshow(masked_array, cmap='jet', aspect='auto')
```